# Recovering a GPT damaged partition

Tags: gparted, gpt, gdisk

**Problem:** 4TB drive can't be mounted. The drive is visible in GParted and gdisk, but the GPT partition is reported as damaged.

**Background information:** Initially my setup consisted of 2 storage devices. My primary drive is an SSD with Windows 10. My secondary drive is a 4TB HDD.This setup worked well. I wanted to run Linux on occasion so I installed another HDD. When installing Linux I removed the SATA and power from the Windows SSD and plugged them into the new HDD. I removed only the SATA cable from the 4TB HDD. I then proceed to installing CentOS. Finally reconnected the 4TB HDD, the SSD, and installed a new SATA cable and connected it to the new HDD. Using the boot menu I am able to switch between my Windows 10 and Linux installations. At this point I noticed that the 4TB HDD was not appearing in Windows or Linux.

**Technical Information:** I can't see the 4TB HDD in Windows using disk partition. I can see the drive in Linux using gpart GUI and gdisk on the command line. 2 partitions are seen by the drive in gdisk and GParted.

*Using Gparted:*
When the drive is scanned by I get a prompt titled "Libparted Bug Found!" with text that reads "end of file while reading /dev/sda". Options are to retry, cancel, or ignore.

When I press ignore I get a prompt titled "Libparted Bug Found!" with text that reads "The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used." Options OK or cancel.

*Using gdisk:*
    GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.6

```
Type device filename, or press <Enter> to exit: /dev/sda
Caution: invalid main GPT header, but valid backup; regenerating main header
from backup!

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 7814037168 sectors, 3.6 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 07A40EF7-3F5A-42B8-BE06-6BC4D40492ED
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 7814037134
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 3693 sectors (1.8 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              34          262177   128.0 MiB   0C01  Microsoft reserved part
   2          264192      7814035455   3.6 TiB     0700  Basic data partition

Command (? for help): i
Partition number (1-2): 1
Partition GUID code: E3C9E316-0B5C-4DB8-817D-F92DF00215AE (Microsoft reserved)
Partition unique GUID: 07987030-5C4E-4936-9BCD-129C622C99DF
First sector: 34 (at 17.0 KiB)
Last sector: 262177 (at 128.0 MiB)
Partition size: 262144 sectors (128.0 MiB)
Attribute flags: 0000000000000000
Partition name: 'Microsoft reserved partition'

Command (? for help): i
Partition number (1-2): 2
Partition GUID code: EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7 (Microsoft basic data)
Partition unique GUID: 9A23AFCE-2382-4C1C-AC0B-F25E6428E4C4
First sector: 264192 (at 129.0 MiB)
Last sector: 7814035455 (at 3.6 TiB)
Partition size: 7813771264 sectors (3.6 TiB)
Attribute flags: 0000000000000000
Partition name: 'Basic data partition'

Command (? for help): v

Caution: Partition 1 doesn't begin on a 8-sector boundary. This may
result in degraded performance on some modern (2009 and later) hard disks.

Consult http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-4kb-sector-disks/
for information on disk alignment.

No problems found. 3693 free sectors (1.8 MiB) available in 2
segments, the largest of which is 2014 (1007.0 KiB) in size.
```

How should gdisk or GParted be used in order to fix the damaged GPT partition without destroying the data on the drive?

Comment: Could you please clarify how Ubuntu is related to this question? This seems like a Windows/CentOS issue....

Comment: My thought was they are both Linux derivatives. I did a search on askbuntu for CentOS and got other hits so I though it would be okay to post. Now that your questing it I did some looking and see there is a specific Unix & Linux SE site. I can't find how to migrate my question or I would do it now.